# How to Add a class on the selected element and remove form others?

Tags: jquery, menu, anchor

This is my HTML:

```
<ul class="menu menu-primary">
    <li class="current has-children">
        <a href="">Home</a>
        <span class="menu-item-toggle">
            <span></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="current-children"><a href="" class="">Homepage-1</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="" class="">Home-2</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="" class="">Home-3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now what I want is that on click of "menu-item-toggle", "menu-expand" gets added to respective "li.has-children" and remove from other li's.

Heres my script:

```
$('ul.menu li.has-children').each(function () {
    var menuItem = $(this)
    var menuToggle = $('<span class="menu-item-toggle"><span></span></span>')

    menuToggle.insertAfter(menuItem.find('> a')).on('click', function () {
        menuItem.toggleClass('menu-expand');
        menuItem.nextAll().removeClass('menu-expand');
        menuItem.prevAll().removeClass('menu-expand');
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('ul.menu li.has-children').click(function () {
    $('ul.menu li.has-children').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('menu-expand');
    });
    $(this).addClass('menu-expand');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by the following way.

```
 $('ul.menu li.has-children').each(function () {
        var menuItem = $(this)
        var menuToggle = $('<span class="menu-item-toggle"><span></span></span>')
        $(this).removeClass('menu-expand');
        menuToggle.insertAfter(menuItem.find('> a')).on('click', function () {
            menuItem.toggleClass('menu-expand');
            menuItem.nextAll().removeClass('menu-expand');
            menuItem.prevAll().removeClass('menu-expand');
            $(this).addClass('menu-expand');
        })
    })
```

Comment: implement it inside your onlclick event it will work